# No record display when grid is empty - Kendo React Grid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

We have a Kendo React grid and we need to show the No record found the message when data is empty.

```
 <Grid
                        sortable
                        filterable
                        expandField="expanded"
                        detail={props => <DetailComponent
                            {...props}
                            onChange={this.handleDetailTemplateChange}
                            changed={[]}

                        />}
                        onExpandChange={this.expandChange}
                        pageable={this.state.pageable}
//                        scrollable="true"
                        editField="inEdit"
                        data={this.state.providersPage}
                        sort={this.state.sort}
                        onSortChange={this.handleSortChange}
                        filter={this.state.filter}
                        onFilterChange={this.handleFilterChange}
                        onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
                        total={this.state.total}
                        skip={this.state.skip}
                        pageSize={this.state.pageSize}
                        onItemChange={this.handleProviderChange}
                        resizable>

                        <GridColumn field="affiliationRelationshipStatusName" title="Network Relationship" filterCell={this.CategoryFilterCell} 
                                    cell={NetworkRelationshipCell} width="245px"/>
                         <GridColumn field="address" title="Places" filterable={false} cell={NetworkPlaceCell} 
                         width="245px"/> 
</Grid>
```

See Kendo documentation but couldn't find any solution. Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

The packages comes with GridNoRecords exported component, that you can place inside the grid. It will be rendered when there are no records.
Import it as you import the grid itself:

```
        import { Grid, GridColumn, GridNoRecords } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid'
```

Then place it inside the grid, with some content inside it.

```
        <Grid data={[]}>
            <GridNoRecords>
                There is no data available
            </GridNoRecords>
            <GridColumn field="id" />
            <GridColumn field="name" />
        </Grid>
```

The above example is from the [official documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridNoRecords/). I believe this is what you are looking for.